# Google Play Services 9.2.0 Selective Compile Awareness API

Tags: android, google-play-services, google-awareness

I'm trying to use the new Awareness API in an app but the only way that I can include it in my code is by using

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.2.0'
```

in my gradle file.

I tried using

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-awareness:9.2.0'
```

but it doesn't seem to exist.

Does anyone know what the correct compile path for selective compile of the awareness API is?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @XaverKapeller It doest exist, just hidden :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It actually does exist.

//Awareness API

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-contextmanager:9.2.0'
```

Comment: Awesome! :) Worked! Just curious how you found that though! Where can I look the next time I have this issue?

Comment: Sneaky. I guess they haven't published it under its correct name yet. Seems the Awareness API was once called ContextManager API. ;)

Comment: @joaomgcd You can look on Bintray - the website behind the maven repository jcenter - and look for the package in the play services group. I actually scrolled through the packages but didn't find any mention of the Awareness API. Turns out that's because its currently published under a different name.

Comment: You could also print the dependency graph with the gradle task `dependencies` and look for a repository that might be it. Could be that this is what @buddhabath did.

Comment: I was a desperate man (reached dex limit with full lib) and my googling skills are out of this world. (Found it on reddit)

Comment: How friendly of them to not include it in the documentation. Thank you for this!!

Comment: If anyone else stumbles on this, it is now documented for 9.4.0 at https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup

Comment: As of play services 9.6.0, this has been renamed to awareness. See this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39703220/google-awareness-api-v9-6-is-missing)

Answer (score 1):

Today you have to include:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-awareness:10.2.4'
```

If you want to know the latest Dependency you can use my web tool called [DependencyLookup](https://rekire.github.io/DependencyLookup/?so=38100627).

Comment: That did it for me, thanks `implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-awareness:11.8.0"`