# Which dependency is required for Awareness API?

Tags: android, google-awareness

I want to check out the new Awareness API which is quite new. I’m using Play Services 9.0.2. The documentation has [this example](https://developers.google.com/awareness/android-api/get-started#declare_android_permissions_in_androidmanifestxml):

```
GoogleApiClient client = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(context)
        .addApi(Awareness.API)
        .build();
client.connect();
```

However, there is no hint which dependency needs to been added. Any idea?

Comment: at the moment, apparently, the whole play-services library.

Comment: @muratgu that is not true. I found it out.

Comment: Already answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38100627/google-play-services-9-2-0-selective-compile-awareness-api

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found it out: I need to upgrade to PlayServices 9.2.0 and the dependency is hidden in `play-services-contextmanager`. Just add those dependencies and here we go:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-awareness:10.2.4'
```

<sup>Please use the latest play services library, at the time I updated this answer it was 10.2.4</sup>

If you want to know the latest Dependency you can use my web tool called [DependencyLookup](https://rekire.github.io/DependencyLookup/?so=38108696).

Keep in mind that this library was added in the Play Services Repository v31. Make sure that you have at least that version installed in the SDK manager.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the library of *Google Play services* to your project.

> Set up Google Play services
>
> To access the Awareness API, your app's development project must
>   include Google Play services. Download and install the Google Play
>   services component via the SDK Manager and add the library to your
>   project. For details, see the Android guide to setting up Google Play
>   services.

[Source](https://developers.google.com/awareness/android-api/get-started)

Comment: I have the play services added but the class is still not found.

Comment: The Awareness class?

Comment: Yeah, I found the dependency in the meantime.

Answer (score 0):

### Set up Google Play services

To access the Awareness API, your app's development project must include Google Play services. Download and install the Google Play services component via the SDK Manager and add the library to your project. For details, see the Android guide to setting up [Google Play services](https://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html).

which is apparently on the same page you got your code sample from [here](https://developers.google.com/awareness/android-api/get-started)

Comment: Right it is part of the PlayServices but I was searching for the exact dependency.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the times the number of method references in your app exceeds the 65K limit, your app may fail to compile. So in order to mitigate this problem when compiling your app ,specify only the specific Google Play services APIs your app uses, instead of all of them.

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:9.2.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-contextmanager:9.2.0'
```

You will find the complete solution here:
http://xordroid.com/create-intelligent-apps-with-google-awareness-api/

Answer (score 0):

Starting PlayServices v9.6.0, **`contextmanager`** has been changed to **`awareness`**

So, the previous answers won't be working.

The correct dependencies, as of v10.2.4 are

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:10.2.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-awareness:10.2.0'
```