# Google Awareness API v9.6 is missing

Tags: android, google-play-services, google-awareness

I'm interested in new maps styling feature, which is added in 9.6 Google Play Services release, but also I'm using Awareness API. In my `build.gradle` I have

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:9.6.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-contextmanager:9.6.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:9.6.1'
```

and some other play-services/firebase modules. Previously with v9.4 that worked, but now I'm getting `Failed to resolve: com.google.android.gms:play-services-contextmanager:9.6.1`
BTW, all other libs with 9.6 version resolved correctly. Also I tried to use 9.6.0 and 9.+, nothing worked.

**Please, don't suggest adding** `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.6.1'` **because it's increasing compile time dramatically.**

*UPD: just discovered, that Activity Recognition is included in location package, so I don't need awareness. But it's not an answer*

Comment: The issue seems to be with the google itself. There is no 9.6.1 version for the contextmanager, only 9.4.0.

Comment: @SrikarReddy I'm sure it is. Waiting for google guy come and see this)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Starting 9.6.0 it was renamed to "awareness", so you should use

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-awareness:9.6.1'
```

You can check it in "Google Repository rev 35", simply navigate to:

```
ANDROID_HOME/extras/google/m2repository/com/google/android/gms
```

and there you will see that there is no 9.6.0 and 9.6.1 folders inside "play-services-contextmanager" but there is new folder "play-services-awareness" with 9.6.0 and 9.6.1

Not sure is it permanent or temporary, because as you said in documentation it's still named "play-services-contextmanager"

Comment: Special thanks for hint, now I know where to search in such cases

Comment: Thank you so much. This problem was driving me nuts.