# Failed to resolve: com.google.firebase:firebase-storage-common:11.0.1

Tags: android, firebase, gradle, firebase-storage

I am upgrading my Android Studio, Gradle version 2.3 to 2.3.3, also have updated my sdk - API level 26, SDK build tool 26, Google Play Service 41, Google Repository 54.

When I clean my project, I get this error: `Failed to resolve: com.google.firebase:firebase-storage-common:11.0.1`

**build.gradle:**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion '26.0.0'
    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 26
        multiDexEnabled = true
    }

    def applicationVersion = '1.524 20170612'

    dexOptions {
        preDexLibraries = false
        javaMaxHeapSize "2g"
    }

    ...


    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'build.gradle'
        exclude 'build.xml'
        exclude 'META-INF/jersey-module-version'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    }
    allprojects {
        tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
            options.compilerArgs << "-Xlint:deprecation"
        }
    }
}

dependencies {

    compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.9.0.pr1'
    compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.9.0.pr1'
    compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.9.0.pr1'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'

    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:11.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-appindexing:9.8.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-contextmanager:9.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:11.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-nearby:11.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:11.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:11.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:11.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:11.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.4'
    compile 'com.google.zxing:core:3.2.0'
    compile 'com.journeyapps:zxing-android-embedded:3.3.0@aar'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:11.0.1'

    compile 'com.flurry.android:analytics:6.4.2'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:+'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: Refer clearly here, https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup. Mine was working well with these lines     
dependencies {
.....
   compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:9.6.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage-common:9.6.0'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services' // bottom of the file

Comment: Thanks Nandha for response on my question. Tried it , but error is not resolved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error throws because of in GooglePlayService package some changes are happened. They moves some class files and there methods to Firebase pacakge.
Reference link are: https://developers.google.com/android/guides/releases#october_2016_-_version_98
Now need to changes some project link on build.gradle file.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion '26.0.0'
    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 26
        multiDexEnabled = true
    }

    def applicationVersion = '1.20170612'
dexOptions {
    preDexLibraries = false
    javaMaxHeapSize "2g"
}
enter code here
lintOptions {
    checkReleaseBuilds false
    // Or, if you prefer, you can continue to check for errors in release builds,
    // but continue the build even when errors are found:
    abortOnError false

}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
    }
    debug {
        minifyEnabled false
    }
    }
}
dependencies {
compile project(':paymentGatewayCommons')
compile project(':paypal')
compile project(':paytm')
compile project(':payu')
compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.9.0.pr1'
compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.9.0.pr1'
compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.9.0.pr1'
compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:11.0.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-cast-framework:11.0.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:11.0.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-nearby:11.0.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.0.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:11.0.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:11.0.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:11.0.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:11.0.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.0.1'
compile 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.4.+'
compile 'com.google.zxing:core:3.2.0'
compile 'com.journeyapps:zxing-android-embedded:3.3.0@aar'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-appindexing:11.0.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.0.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.0.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:11.0.1'
compile 'com.flurry.android:analytics:6.4.2'
compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:+'


  testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Also change in Main project build.gradle file

```
dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.0'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
```

Answer (score 7):

Firebase [doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup) says:

> Getting a "Could not find" error? Make sure you have
>   the latest Google Repository in the Android SDK manager

You can check your Google Repository version (in Linux):

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Make sure from group `com.google.android.gms` and from group `com.google.firebase` have same version.

For example, current latest version is 11.0.1, therefore all dependencies from `com.google.android.gms` and `com.google.firebase` should have version 11.0.1. In your `dependencies` list following two have a different version. Make sure they too have version 11.0.1.

For achieving that

You will need to migrate
Play Services App indexing to Firebase App indexing. The guide is [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/app-indexing/android/migrate).

According to [Google Awareness API v9.6 is missing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39703220/google-awareness-api-v9-6-is-missing) contextmanager api was changed to [Awareness API](https://developers.google.com/awareness/overview). So you'll also need to update your code accordingly.

Comment: Hello BhalchadraSW, Thanks for response my question. When I am checking on my hard disk Android/sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/google/androd/gms/play-servies-appindexing:9.8.0 is the latest downloaded version.
Android/sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/google/android/gms/play-services-contextmanager:9.4.0 is also latest downloaded version.
Google not provide 11.0.1 version for that.

Comment: I think because you should migrate to [firebase appindexing](https://firebase.google.com/docs/app-indexing/android/migrate)

Comment: Plus migrate contextmanager to [Awareness API](https://developers.google.com/awareness/overview)

Comment: Yes, this worked for me. In my case the vision package was inconsistent and needed to be changed as: `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:11.0.1'`

Answer (score 2):

The best Method to fix this problem is not using the manual method of linking firebase to your app.

I have tried adding latest firebase repo by referring to this 
    [Link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup) .

It showed error " failed to resolve the dependencies"

FireBase recommends adding firebase to your app with the help of FireBase Assistant for Android Studio Version 2.2 and Higher. Manually adding the latest library to build-gradle(module) result in an error as above.

Using Firebase assistant is so easy and 2 step process. For reference, You can use the "Use the Firebase Assistant" section on the same link mentioned above.

It Really worked Out with my Android Studio 2.3.3